# Efficient way to check if files exist and update SQL db accordingly

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to check if files exist in a folder and then if they don't, I want to update my sql database. As of now I am looping through an array of id's that should have a number corresponding to the file number in the database. This means that I am querying the sql database multiple times vs one time. Is it possible and more efficient to make just one query? Here is what my code looks like:

```
$photo_status = "SELECT id FROM photo_set_table WHERE Photo_added = 1";


$photo_added = mysql_query($photo_status);
if (!$photo_added) {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}


$path = '/home/aXXXXXXX/public_html/';
$path .= '/images_android/images/';
$no_photo_array = array();

while($added = mysql_fetch_array($photo_added))
{

    if(!file_exists($path.$added[0].'.jpg')){
        array_push($no_photo_array, $added[0]);
    }

}//while added

$count_changes = 0;
foreach ($no_photo_array as $value) {
    $change_status = "UPDATE photo_set_table SET Photo_added = 0 WHERE id = $value";
    $photo_added2 = mysql_query($change_status);
    if (!$photo_added2) {
      die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    } else {
        $count_changes++;       
    }
} //foreach ($no_photo_array....
echo "The number of affected lines is: ".$count_changes;

mysql_close($connection);
```

Comment: It might be a bit more efficient to glob() the directory and compare the list of files with the list from the database with something like array_diff().  Also, mysql_* functions are deprecated, you should get rid of them and replace with mysqli or PDO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
$count_changes = 0;
if (count($no_photo_array) > 0) {
    $sInClause = implode(',', $no_photo_array);
    $sSql = "UPDATE photo_set_table SET Photo_added = 0 WHERE id IN (" . $sInClause . ")";
    $bStatus = mysql_query($sSql);
    if ($bStatus) {
        $count_changes = mysql_affected_rows();
    } else {
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }
} //foreach ($no_photo_array....
echo "The number of affected lines is: ".$count_changes;
```

Comment: this seems to work ok althought the mysql_affected_rows method doesn't work. I havent had the time to try out how the two scripts compare, but this is what I was looking to do. Thanks for the help!